# Text Extraction from real world messy files

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

```
WET READ: ___ ___ ___ 7:31 PM
 Persistent right lower lung opacity and right pleural effusion. Effusion
   perhaps slightly decreased since radiograph dated ___.
 ______________________________________________________________________________
                                 FINAL REPORT

PA AND LATERAL CHEST RADIOGRAPH.

TECHNIQUE:  AP upright portable radiograph of chest was reviewed in comparison
to prior radiograph from ___.

 
 As compared to ___ there is interval improvement of pulmonary edema. 
 Right lower lobe consolidation with internal cavitation surrounded by pleural
 effusion appears to be grossly unchanged in the short interim.  There is no
 evidence of progression of left consolidation.  Small amount of left pleural
 effusion is noted.
```

I have text files like this, I want to extract data from the files after "FINAL REPORT". Means I want to delete everything from my text files up to and including "FINAL REPORT".

I have tried regular expression, But couldn't find method to do that.

Comment: Just read it line by line.  Make a flag called "keep" that starts out False, and set it True if you find "FINAL REPORT".  Then, you decide whether to write the line to output based on the "keep" flag you

Answer (score 1):

Just do it line by line:

```
def copy( infile ):
    tempname = infile + '.tmp'
    if os.path.exists( tempname ):
        os.remove( tempname )

    keep = False
    with open(infile) as fin, open(tempname,'w') as fout:
        for line in fin
            if "FINAL REPORT" in line:
                keep = True
            if keep:
                print( line.strip(), file=fout )
    os.remove( infile )
    os.rename( tempfile, infile )
```

Comment: def copy( infile, outfile):
    keep = False
    with open(infile) as f:
      data = f.read()
      print(data)
      
      for line in data:
        print(line)
        if "FINAL REPORT" in line:
            keep = True
        if keep:
            print( line.strip(), file=outfile )
              




copy('/content/s50365346.txt')               """" I was trying to read the .txt file from a folder and run it through you code, it wasn't working for me.  Will you please see my code, and let me know, where i make any mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: You did not pass an output file.  If you want to do it in place, you'll need to write to a temporary and rename it afterward.